# Bootstrap Popover arrow will not change with data-placement change once already set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**Goal:**

I am creating a scheduling UI using clocks with 15 minute segments that can either be occupied with a meeting, or empty. I have a clock image on my page, and when you click on the circle, a bootstrap popover comes up on the outside of the pieslice that you clicked on (giving a description of that time and where there is a meeting or not)

---

**Problem:**

Depending on what quadrant of the clock you click on (top, bottom, left, right) I change the data-placement of the popover so the arrow will be pointing towards the clock. This works the first time I do it, but after that, every time I reposition the popover for a new click, the arrow direction remains the same.

---

**Code:**

JS:

```
    var direction = getArrowDirection(seg); //finds the direction the arrow should face
    var popover =  $('#generalPopover'); 
    popover.attr("data-placement", direction);
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    $(".meetingPopover").popover("show");
```

HTML:

```
<div data-toggle="popover" title="Meeting at Opus: 3:30pm to 5pm" 
data-content="Some content inside the popover" style="float: left;" 
class="meetingPopover" id="generalPopover">Popover</div>
```

---

**Question:**

Why is the arrow not changing direction after I set it the first time? Shouldn't this be changing the data-placement which dictates where the arrow points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you grab the popover instance like this:

```
var popover = $('.reply').data('bs.popover');
```

Then, to redraw the popover, use the `.setContent()` method:

```
popover.setContent();
```

I found out browsing the source: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/popover.js

So, in your example, try:

```
thisVal.attr('data-content',data).data('bs.popover').setContent();
```

Update

The `setContent()` method also removes the placement class, so you should do:

```
var popover = thisVal.attr('data-content',data).data('bs.popover');
popover.setContent();
popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44RvK

Comment: I'm confused how this solves my problem. Why, in my case, does the direction not change? And what is changing it in your example?

Comment: The `setContent()` method also removes the placement class. You should use this method. That's what changes the direction in my example and that's why is not changing in yours